# radio button is not working

Tags: php, radio-button

```
<form method="POST"/>
FATHER<input type="radio" name="r" value="father">
MOTHER<input type="radio" name="r" value="mother ">
KID<input type="radio" name="r" value="kid ">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>



<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit') {
if(!empty($_POST['r']) || !empty($_POST['r']))
    {
        $h=$_POST['r'];
    }else {
        $h='';
    }
if($h =="father" )  
   {
           echo "1";
   } else if($h =="mother" ) {
           echo "2";
   } else if($h =="kid" ) {
           echo "3";
   }
   }
```

I have 3 radio button id kid , father and mother , when the user clicked on any of the radio button , i have assigned some value for father , mother and kid . When i clicked on the father , its showing me the result but when i click on the mother and kid button , it showing me nothing . Please can anybody help me .

Comment: as a side note, no idea why you are closing the form tag (the last /> should just be >), this has nothing to do with your problem, but might cause some other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$h=$_POST['r'];
```

To:

```
$h=trim($_POST['r']); #this to trim off white spaces you have accidently put on values of radio buttons.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a blank space in "mother " and "kid "

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the value for mother and father. "mother " != "mother" and "father " != "father"

Remove the space and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your HTML: value-tags for kid and mother you have a *space* at the end: `value="kid "` but you compare the submitted `POST` to string `mother` / `kid` *WITHOUT* a space at the end, so it fails.

I would remove the trailig space in your value-tags. Other ways to get your script working is to add a space in your comparing strings or to use the `trim`-function before you compare. `trim` removes all heading/trailing spaces of a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you put space character after mother and kid. Instead of "mother " you can use "mother" and it will work. And I couldn't understand why you repeated same condition on

```
if(!empty($_POST['r']) || !empty($_POST['r']))
```

You can also use switch case for these kind of controls, it makes code more organized. You can find a simple example and information here:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php